# Cloud Run - PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler, google-secret-manager

Super annoying issue going on, and I hope it is something simple that I am missing that someone can point out.

I deployed an app using Cloud Run. I then created a job in Cloud Scheduler using a service account with Owner permissions on my project to generate the OIDC for the Auth header.

The app successfully processes the request, but then within the logic of my app, I am getting the Secret Manager permissions denied error.

My only guess as to what is going on is that the service account I am using in the cloud scheduler is not the one that cloud run is using to authenticate to Secret Manager, but I have granted the Secret Manager Secret Accessor role to every service account I can think of.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the docs, some permissions are not given in any predefined role and need to be given explicitly.

Comment: What service account is your Cloud Run service deployed as? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity. The default service account doesn't not have permission to access secrets by design. It's not recommended that you use the default service account due to its overly broad permissions.

Comment: I guess I am using the default service account lol. But I explicitly granted the Secret Accessor role to it.

Comment: I switched to using a dedicated service account with the same result

Comment: Is the secret in the same GCP project as the Cloud Run Service?

Comment: Yes it is. The scheduler, the secrets, the cloud run, and everything else is all the same project

Comment: I would suggest updating the question with all the details.  For example, what is the exact error, what does the code look like, what service accounts are in play, what if anything is logged in Cloud Logging.

Comment: There is 2 aspects: What are the API that you call? Share your code to let us know how do you use the libraries. Which service account is used by Cloud Run? Share your Cloud Run configuration (your deployment in command line for example).

Comment: Turning on data access cloud audit logs might also give you a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through all the comments here. I restarted the process using a service account with owner permissions, which worked fine. I then created a new service account and gave it one permission at a time until it fixed the issue.